# LIKE % XX(YY)GG % not working in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, sql-like

I have used Stored procedure to check whether a name exist in a table or not by using the following code snippet..

```
BEGIN
IF ids = 0 THEN
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `table_id` = alb_id AND  name LIKE CONCAT('%',var_name,'%');
END IF;
END
```

I got the solution if the name doesn't contain any special characters or brackets, like XXXX.

If the name contains any brackets means result not came, like XX(YY)GG.

Suggest me for the best solution

Edited:

In this if a name exist already i should not insert it again, for this condition i used this procedure. If it returns mysql_num_rows > 0 means i wont insert, else i will insert the name into my table..

My sample names are,..

- Turning Tables (Live Acoustic)
- Hiding My Heart
- Someone Like You (Live Acoustic)
- Right Now (Na Na Na)
- Keep You Much Longer
- Someone Like You

In the list of name "Someone Like You" and "Someone Like You (Live Acoustic)" are two different names, i want to identify the name "Someone Like You (Live Acoustic)" is already exist or not..

How do i do?

Comment: Here var_name is the variable passed through procedure

Comment: Why is a substring enough to be the same name? I.e. if there's an "Elizabeth" then "Eliza" would meet your WHERE condition, but if there's a "Eliza" first then would "Elizabeth" not meet your condition.

Comment: Could you please add some sample data, the result you get and the result you want to have? The expression that you have in the title of your question is working fine, see [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4da0f/2).

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `stack_test` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `text` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `blur_new`.`stack_test` (`id`, `text`) VALUES ('1', 'run (rabbit) run');
INSERT INTO `blur_new`.`stack_test` (`id`, `text`) VALUES ('2', 'test');

set @a = 'n (rabbit)';
select * from stack_test where text like concat('%',@a,'%');
```

results in:
1    |run (rabbit) run

So, it works.

check the rest of the conditions in where clause

check how are you passing the value

you might gonna have to check you data types. I have a feeling something is not right there